# ember filter on promised inside a model

Tags: ember.js

i have two models:
User:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  books: hasMany('book', { async: true }),
});
```

book:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  state: DS.attr('number'),
});
```

in my of my controller i am getting one user as my model and i want to create a computed property like this

```
  activeBooks: Ember.computed('model.books', function() {
    var books = this.get('model.books').filter(function (book, index, array) {
      // debugger;
      return (this.get('book.state') === 1);
    }.bind(this));
    return books;
  }),
```

but the filter is not working and basically return a empty array. 
P.S 1. i am side loading books alone with user. and at the debugger line i query for `this.get('user.books.length')`  i get the correct number of books for each user. could someone point out what i am doing wrong here?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filterBy` and return the result.

```
activeBooks:Ember.computed('model.books', function() {
 return this.get('model.books').filterBy('state',1);
})
```

You don't need to use `bind(this)` inside filter function.

Comment: thanks for the reply but this still doesn`t work. :(

Comment: By the time computed property is called, are you sure that `this.get('model.books.length')` has the correct value.. `books: hasMany('book', { async: false }),`. this might help I am not sure. I haven't used much ember-data

Comment: yep the `this.get('model.books.length')` has .the correct value.